# Vertical offset when trying to align two div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two div horizontally, I'm using display:inline-block; to align them, but If one is longer than other, the smalliest one is under "a normal line".

Like this : [image: You can see that the "Connexion" div is under the other one]

Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/vqiNkth2

PS : I'm using bootstrap with some pages, and with the header/footer, but not the content in this one.

Comment: the smalliest one is under "a normal line". << not clear

Comment: Try to give vertical-align: top; to .widget-box. Or if you want you can give middle :)

Comment: @YehiaAwad > I'm sorry, I don't speak english very well and even in my own language I can't make it clear xD.

Comment: @SkyWookie > It works with vertical-align, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have given display inline block so make sure yo give vertical align top to both div's .. your problem will be solved.. and for some reason the link you provided not working.